# How to align text within a FooterTemplate cell in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview, cell, text-alignment

How to align text within a FooterTemplate cell in a GridView

I tried the following but the text is still centered (there is a parent center tag):

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <span style="size:100%; padding:0; text-align: right">Total:&nbsp;</span>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the parent column of the template try setting `FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <span>Total: </span>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

works as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use display:block which replaces size:100% (which doesn't exist, AFAIK)

```
<FooterTemplate>
  <span style="display:block; padding:0; text-align: right">Total: </span>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Grid-view would in the end be rendered as a table itself hence, using basic CSS selectors, we can solve the problem, I used the following to fix the same problem that I was facing, hope it helps anyone else looking for this thread

```
    tr:last-of-type td {
        align-content: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Hope that helped.